# How to remove a full stop from the end of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to **update** my table because a number of fields in a column have got a fullstop on the end, i need to remove this.

So, in TableA, Field1: the data looks like

```
1002243.    
1007053.    
1007403.    
1104098.    
1110010.
```

*NOTE*: Not all the fields are the same length.

I need to remove the full stops.

Im using SQL Server 2005, cheers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Field1 = LEFT(Field1 ,LEN(Field1)-1)
WHERE Field1 LIKE '%.'
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked great but I had to add an extra % for them to be located in the where clause. **WHERE Field1 LIKE '%.%'**

Comment: @PDB - That changes the meaning of the query. That finds all values which contain a `.` anywhere then removes the last character (whatever it is). `SELECT 1 WHERE '1002243.' LIKE '%.'` works fine!

Comment: If it didn't work for you, then you likely have one or more unprintable characters  (probably a line break, carriage return or tab) in the field after the period.

Comment: @HLGEM - But then the dot wouldn't be removed either, it would remove the unprintable character surely? I can't think of any explanation for why the modified query would work but the original one wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have data after the period.  Try this to see:

`Print '[' + Field1 + ']'` and see if you get something like this:

`[101. ]`

There is a space after the period.

Comment: I thought something like that might explain the OP's reported behaviour too but [trailing blanks, in the expression to which the pattern is matched, are ignored](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)