# Remove a full stop from the end of data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is something similar to this question about 
[How to remove a full stop from the end of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443734/how-to-remove-a-full-stop-from-the-end-of-data)

But in this case the data field can be like this

**MyVal**

```
 abcd.          ->>expected   abcd
 abcd..                       abcd
 abcd .                       abcd 
 abcd ..                      abcd
 ab.abb...                    ab.abb
```

etc....

I can do something like

```
Select case when like '%.' then substring(MyVal ,1,len(MyVal )-1)
       case when like '%..' then substring(MyVal ,1,len(MyVal )-2)
```

by matching every kind of pattern there going to be..
Since this is manual way, I am looking for a general way that can remove any number of full stop may occur after the value field.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have spaces or full stops occurring within the data itself? If not, you could just use `LEFT` to truncate at the first space or full stop.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense. Are you able to elaborate on the rule for spaces a bit more. Reason for this is there is a space after abcd in the expected answer on the third row, but none on the fourth row. I am not sure if that's intended, or just a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select substring(MyVal, 1, len(MyVal)+1-patindex('%[^.]%', reverse(MyVal)))
```

**Update:**
If you want to remove spaces as well you can use this instead.

```
select substring(MyVal, 1, len(MyVal)+1-patindex('%[^. ]%', reverse(MyVal)))
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67891)

Comment: Excellent... !! what happens if  text like "dui. ." ??

Comment: Though this won't work for values like `'ab.cd   . ..'` or `'abcd       ... . ..'` or `'abcd... . ..'`, whereas my approach does. But you're right that mine doesn't like points in the middle.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: using my limited knowledge of RegEx, adding a space before the '.' seems to do the trick - '%[^ .]%'

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have updated my answer with a version that removes the spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible without using T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @Example varchar(max) = 'Hello, Dave....'

SET @Example = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Example))

WHILE SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Example), 0, 2) = '.'
BEGIN
    SET @Example = SUBSTRING(@Example, 0, LEN(@Example) - 1)
END

SELECT @Example
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', MyVal) > 0 
        THEN RTRIM(LEFT(MyVal, CHARINDEX('.', MyVal) - 1))
        ELSE MyVal 
       END  As NewValue
FROM Table
```

Tested with:

```
declare @t1 table(MyVal varchar(20));
insert into @t1 values('abcd.');
insert into @t1 values('abcd..');
insert into @t1 values('abcd .');
insert into @t1 values('abcd ..');
insert into @t1 values('abcd   . ..');
insert into @t1 values('abcd... . ..');

SELECT   MyVal As FullStopVal
      ,  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', MyVal) > 0 
          THEN RTRIM(LEFT(MyVal, CHARINDEX('.', MyVal) - 1))
          ELSE MyVal  END  As NewValue
FROM @t1
```

**EDIT**: My approach doesn't like points in the middle of the value as @MikaelEriksson has already noted, but it works for values like

```
abcd   . .. 
abcd       ... . ..
abcd... . ..
```

<sub>unlike his :)</sub>

Comment: I guess this wont work if you have a `.` in the middle of the string somewhere.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Question is to remove full stop from end of the data. So Tim is 100% right.

Comment: @Murtaza - Not sure you understood my point. If you have a string 'ab.cd.' the result will be `ab`. That is removing a bit more than the trailing `.`(s).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - cool i understood your point. and Tim is 50% right :)

Comment: Thanks Tim, anyway it give me an error **Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Edited my answer. It didn't work so far for values without a `point` ;-)

Comment: This will remove the rest of line if the text like "abcd.aabbbcc..". So result will be abcd??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Yes, as Mikael has already mentioned. I thought that would be the reason why you have accepted his answer. I assume i've missed one or two `REVERSE`, but i'm running out of time now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RemoveFullStopsFromEnd] (@Input varchar(255))
Returns varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(255) 
    SELECT @OutPut = @Input

    While (Len(@Output) > 0) and (SUBSTRING(@Output,Len(@Output),1) = '.')
    Begin
       SELECT @Output = substring(@Output ,1,len(@Output )-1)
    End
    RETURN @Output
END
```

Usage

```
 select dbo.fn_RemoveFullStopsFromEnd('abcd..')
```

Can easily be amended if you want to remove the spaces as well as the fullstops from the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(somestrings VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('abcd.')
, ('abcd..')
, ('abcd .')
, ('abcd ..')
, ('ab.abb...');
SELECT somestrings=LEFT(somestrings,LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(somestrings,'.', ' ')))) FROM @t;
```

Result:

```
somestrings
--------------------
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
ab.abb
```